# How to access TextArea from code-behind from a MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, textarea

I have a TextArea in my Content page:

```
<textarea id="taskNotes" runat="server" class="taskNotes"></textarea>
```

Also a Label in my Content page:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="lblStartDate" Text="TEST"></asp:Label>
```

In my MasterPage I can access the label like this:

```
lblStartDate = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)ContentMain.FindControl("lblStartDate");
```

How can I access the TextArea the same way I am accessing the Label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var txtTaskNotes = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea)ContentMain.FindControl("taskNotes");
```

That should do it. But it's probably wiser to populate protected properties in the master page from the content page. That way you're not tying the master page to a single content page layout.

Comment: var txtTaskNotes needs to be a global declaration but I can't use `var` as a global declaration :/

Comment: What do you mean by "global"? If you want the scope to be for the whole master page, you can set it up as a property of the class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net, you want to use **TextBox** with `TextMode="MultiLine"`. It'll render as **TextArea**.

```
<asp:TextBox id="TaskNotesTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" 
    Columns="10" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Then you can access it like you did your label -

```
var taskNotesTextBox = (TextBox)ContentMain.FindControl("TaskNotesTextBox");
```

Comment: My TextArea has to be 100% in height and width inside the DIV that it is in, and with TextBox I couldn't get it to display correctly :/

Comment: **TextBox with MultiLine** is nothing to do with Height and width; it just renders **textarea** tag - *same as in your question*. If you want 100% in Height and Width, you need to manipulate with CSS.